# git svn complaining about Path is not locked

Tags: windows, git, svn, locking, cygwin

I am using git-svn (from cygwin) and I've done several git commits on my local. I've already done `git svn rebase` and it checked out the latest changes in SVN and it successfully merged with my local git copy.

```
C:\src\git\MyProject>git svn rebase
Current branch master is up to date.

C:\src\git\MyProject>git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

C:\src\gitsvn\MyProject>git svn dcommit
Committing to http://mysvnrepo/svn/MyProject ...
        M       .gitignore
        M       trunk/module/src/main/webapp/file_1.html
        M       trunk/module/src/main/webapp/js/file_2.js
        A       trunk/module/src/main/webapp/js/file_3.js
        M       trunk/module/src/main/webapp/js/file_4.js
        M       trunk/module/src/main/webapp/js/file_5.js
        M       trunk/module/src/main/webapp/file_6.html
        M       trunk/module/src/main/webapp/file_7.html
Path is not locked: No lock on path '/svn/MyProject/!svn/wrk/0c6b9b9e-3155-41d8-aa30-979cc5815cee/trunk/module/src/main/webapp/file_8.html' (Status 423 on PUT Request): Server sent unexpected return value (423 Locked) in response to PUT request for '/svn/MyProject/!svn/wrk/0c6b9b9e-3155-41d8-aa30-979cc5815cee/trunk/module/src/main/webapp/file_8.html' at /usr/lib/git-core/git-svn line 922
```

Any ideas what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to do an svn unlock to fix this.